# Convert ARRAY<STRING> to STRING in HIVE

Tags: postgresql, hive

I have collect_set(label) values and wanted to convert it to string

```
SELECT users, collect_set(label) as pets from users_table group by users;
```

so that `["dog", "cat", "lion"]` would become `["dog", "cat", "lion"]` but in STRING format